# Prove Using L'Hopital's Rule And Mean Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

how I can prove, for a function, $f(x)$ is differentiable such that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=L\neq 0$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)$$ exists. Prove so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=0$. I have to use L'Hopital's Rule, and The Mean Value Theorem, do it 2 times.

1. How to prove using L'Hopital's Rule. I want to convert to indeterminate form. But I don't know the function, it is a random function. I converted this to $\frac{e^{x}f(x)}{e^x}$. What to do next?
2. How to prove using The Mean Value Theorem. I think I can use Mean Value Theorem to $f(x)$ on the interval (x, x+1), where x can be any number. And then calculate to $x\rightarrow\infty$. How to do that?

I have to prove this both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch:
1.$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x f(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f’(x)+f(x))\,,$$
which implies
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}f’(x)+L\,.$$

2.$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f’(\xi)h \,,$$
yields
$$L-L=\lim_{x\to\infty}f’(x) h\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

As shown in Baby Rudin we can apply L'Hopital's Rule as long as the denominator tends to $\infty$; it is not necessary that we have $\frac {\infty} {\infty}$ form. So apply the rule to $\lim \frac {f(x)} x$ to show that $f'(x) \to 0$.

Hint for proof using  MVT: If $f'(x) \ to l >0$ the $f(n+1)-f(n) \geq \frac l 2 $ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Show using this that $(f(n)$ is not even bounded.